# Google App Engine - Python 3 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-import, pytz

I'm trying to deploy to Google App Engine in the standard Python37 Environment. I had a previous version working that didn't use pytz or requests however did use external python libraries.

After adding these dependencies and deploying then viewing the website I get a 500 error. Looking at the logs it says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies) say that the dependencies for Python applications are declared in a standard requirements.txt file. Which I have done.

Contents of requirements.txt

> click==6.7
>      Flask==1.0.2
>      geojson==2.4.0
>      itsdangerous==0.24
>      Jinja2==2.10
>      MarkupSafe==1.0
>      pkg-resources==0.0.0
>      pymongo==3.7.1
>      pytz==2018.5
>      Werkzeug==0.14.1

My app.yaml

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Start of main.py

```
import json
import time
import pytz
import requests
```

The error from the Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, 
in spawn_worker 
    worker.init_process() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", 
line 104, in init_process 
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 
129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 
138, in load_wsgi 
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, 
in wsgi 
    self.callable = self.load() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 
52, in load return 
    self.load_wsgiapp() 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 
41, in load_wsgiapp 
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in 
import_app 
    __import__(module) 
File "/srv/main.py", line 4, in <module> 
    import pytz 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'`enter code here`
```

I have installed and tested these modules locally on GAE and verified they work. The errors only come when deploying. Any suggestions on how to fix these errors and deploy successfully would be greatly appreciated.

> edit:
>
> I've updated my requirements.txt to add requests and to remove
>   pkg-resources as that started to give errors on build. Contents of
>   requirements.txt
>
> > click==6.7
> >        Flask==1.0.2
> >        geojson==2.4.0
> >        itsdangerous==0.24
> >        Jinja2==2.10
> >        MarkupSafe==1.0
> >        pymongo==3.7.1
> >        pytz==2018.5
> >        requests==2.18.4
> >        Werkzeug==0.14.1

Comment: You haven't added `requests` to `requirements.txt`

Comment: Apologies, I used pip freeze of the wrong env. I've added requests and thats sorted that issue however the pytz error remains. I'll edit the post to mention this

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy the following app:

In `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

In `requirements.txt`:

```
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
geojson==2.4.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pymongo==3.7.1
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.18.4
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

In `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

import pytz

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return pytz.VERSION
```

This successfully returns the version of `pytz`.

Are you sure the new requirements file contains `pytz` and is being deployed? You can check by navigating in the Google Cloud Console to:

**Resources** > **App Engine** > **Services**, then in the row with your service, **Diagnose** > **Tools** > **Source**. From there you can find the `requirements.txt` file and verify that it contains `pytz==2018.5`.